# How to install gulp without npm on a shared hosting?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, npm, gulp

On my shared hosting I would like to have access to gulp (`gulp watch`) to compile my LESS assets into CSS. To install gulp I must have npm installed as well.

Unfortunately hosting administrator refused to install npm. **Is there any other way to get gulp working on my server**?

My `gulpfile.js` is presented below:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    connect = require('gulp-connect'),
    less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    connect.server({
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('less', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/less/app.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .on('error', console.log.bind(console))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*',
        'bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['less']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['webserver', 'less', 'fonts', 'watch']);
```

Probably I would need to do the same with bower. Making long story short - I just developed my small tiny project on my OS X MAMP localhost where I did all the stuff in terminal (`bower search etc. gulp watch etc.`)

In terms of my hosting **I also have access to the shell** via `ssh -l login host`.

Thank you for any hints or even a clear answer that it's impossible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can not use gulp without node, but gulp is devel tool.

I think you not need gulp on production server. On production server usually you give files processed with gulp, but no gulp directly.

Comment: Agreed. You should be developing not on your production server. Then your watch task will initiate the transfer to the production server.

Comment: I think, that transfer to production server is task for CI server, or deployment tool (for example dependent on versioning hook). Not for gulp watch.

Comment: Gulp watch is just a step in the deployment toolchain. You set up a watch folder with a 3rd-party tool, and when that folder receives new contents, it uploads. It's the perfect match for a build script, regardless of whether it is Grunt, Gulp, Ant, or what have you. Development shouldn't happen on the production server, period.

Comment: @milanlempera, all clear now. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
    connect.server({
        livereload: true
    });
});
```

This is a gulp task never needed on production.

```
gulp.task('less', function() {
    gulp.src('assets/less/app.less')
        .pipe(less())
        .on('error', console.log.bind(console))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});
// ...
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('assets/less/*.less', ['less']);
});
```

These are gulp task never needed on production. You should be putting the compiled CSS files onto the server, perhaps only the compiled CSS and not the .less files.

```
gulp.task('fonts', function() {
    gulp.src([
        'bower_components/bootstrap/fonts/*',
        'bower_components/fontawesome/fonts/*'
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('fonts'));
});
```

This is a gulp task never needed on production. You can simply put those files on the server in the compiled destination.

In short, just put your compiled files on prod. Gulp is a **build tool**. Push the **build** to production, not the source code.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use NPM, even if your administrator won't install it (or node) for you:

1. Download the standalone version of Node (node.exe)
2. Clone the NPM project from Github (which is a standard node project) and place it in the same folder as the node.exe file
3. Use npm as follows: `node.exe npm install gulp` or `C:\Users\me\some-folder-you-can-write-to\node.exe npm install gulp`